# Strange behavior of std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, c++17, std-pair

Absolutely don't understand, why this code:

```
vector<int>v={1,2,3,4,5};
vector<pair<int,int>> pairs;
pairs.push_back(make_pair(1, 1));
for (auto el:v) {
   for (auto p:pairs) {
      pairs[0].second++;
      cout<<p.second;
   }
}
```

*prints "12345"*, and this code:

```
vector<int>v={1,2,3,4,5};
vector<pair<int,int>> pairs;
pairs.push_back(make_pair(1, 1));
for (auto el:v) {
   for (auto p:pairs) {
      p.second++;
      cout<<p.second;
   }
}
```

*prints "22222"*
(The only difference is in changing ***pairs[0].second++***   on   ***p.second++***)

Comment: In `for (auto p : pairs)`, `p` is a copy of an element in `pairs`, whereas `pairs[0]` is definitely the actual element in `pairs`. Use ``for (auto &p : pairs)` to refer to elements in `pairs`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second loop you increment a copy of the element. Use

```
for(auto& …
```